# Shortcode insertion in tab

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, shortcode, tabs

I created a plugin that displays staff people using a shortcode with custom category from a post type. eg. [board-members term="team1"] It works fine but only on a page or post. When I paste the shortcode into a tab (using whistles by Justin Tadlock) the profiles display outside the tab, above the tabs in the page body. what could I do to make it display inside the tab? This is the code...

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/post-type.php'); //file that registers CPT

function wporg_shortcodes_init(){
function wporg_shortcode($atts = []) {
     extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'term' => 'columns'
    ), $atts ) );

    $custom_taxonomy = $atts['term'];       

    // add query of custom post type board_members      
            $recentPosts = new WP_Query
            (array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => array('board_members'), 'columns' => $custom_taxonomy ));              
            while( $recentPosts->have_posts() ) :  $recentPosts->the_post();  ?>

                    <div class="b-thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail') ?></div>
                    <p class="b-info">
                    <span class="b-name"><?php the_title(); ?></span><br />                                       
                    <span class="b-country"><?php the_field('country'); ?></span><br />
                    <span class="b-position"><?php the_field('position'); ?></span><br />
                    <span class="b-content"><?php printf(get_the_content()); ?></span><br />
                </p>                

                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>         
        <?php endwhile; ?>      
   <?php        

    }
   add_shortcode('board-members', 'wporg_shortcode');
  }
 add_action('init', 'wporg_shortcodes_init');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to wrap your shortcode contents in `ob_start()`and `return ob_get_clean()`

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/post-type.php'); //file that registers CPT

function wporg_shortcodes_init(){
function wporg_shortcode($atts = []) {
     extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'term' => 'columns'
    ), $atts ) );

    $custom_taxonomy = $atts['term'];       

    ob_start(); // <- works like magic

    // add query of custom post type board_members      
            $recentPosts = new WP_Query
            (array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => array('board_members'), 'columns' => $custom_taxonomy ));              
            while( $recentPosts->have_posts() ) :  $recentPosts->the_post();  ?>

                    <div class="b-thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail') ?></div>
                    <p class="b-info">
                    <span class="b-name"><?php the_title(); ?></span><br />                                       
                    <span class="b-country"><?php the_field('country'); ?></span><br />
                    <span class="b-position"><?php the_field('position'); ?></span><br />
                    <span class="b-content"><?php printf(get_the_content()); ?></span><br />
                </p>                

                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>         
        <?php endwhile; ?>      
   <?php        

   return ob_get_clean(); // <- more magic

    }
   add_shortcode('board-members', 'wporg_shortcode');
  }
 add_action('init', 'wporg_shortcodes_init');
```

You can also modify the shortcode to return a single string, the following should work as well:

```
function wporg_shortcodes_init(){
  function wporg_shortcode($atts = []) {
     extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'term' => 'columns'
    ), $atts ) );

    $custom_taxonomy = $atts['term'];       

    $output = '';

    // add query of custom post type board_members      
    $recentPosts = new WP_Query
    (array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => array('board_members'), 'columns' => $custom_taxonomy ));              
    while( $recentPosts->have_posts() ) :  $recentPosts->the_post();

        $output .= '<div class="b-thumb">'.the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail').'</div>';
        $output .= '<p class="b-info">';
          $output .= '<span class="b-name">'.the_title().'</span><br />';
          $output .= '<span class="b-country">'.the_field('country').'</span><br />';
          $output .= '<span class="b-position">'.the_field('position').'</span><br />';
          $output .= '<span class="b-content">'.printf(get_the_content()).'</span><br />';
        $output .= '</p>                ';

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $output;

  }
 add_shortcode('board-members', 'wporg_shortcode');
}
add_action('init', 'wporg_shortcodes_init');
```

Comment: Glad I could help @Artus I've elaborated a bit above because there's more than one way to handle this. Also, is there a reason you're calling `wp_reset_postdata` within the loop? Normally those go after a loop https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata

Comment: Thanks about the reset part. You were right. The second version didn't work tho. Even after adding the ob_start() part. It prints everything out of the tab and inside the tab numbers appear.  Also the code editor shows unmatched curly braces which I don't see why. Thanks a lot anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want content to display in a specific spot, you will need to wrap the content in a `<div>` with a 'class', where the 'class' has the CSS you need to display the content.

The shortcode works on pages/posts because the shortcode is contained within the content of the page/post, in the `<div>` that surrounds the post content.

You will need to make a class (called 'myshortcode') of and use that in your loop:

```
<div class='myshortcode'>
 <div class="b-thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail') ?></div>
                    <p class="b-info">
                    <span class="b-name"><?php the_title(); ?></span><br />                                       
                    <span class="b-country"><?php the_field('country'); ?></span><br />
                    <span class="b-position"><?php the_field('position'); ?></span><br />
                    <span class="b-content"><?php printf(get_the_content()); ?></span><br />
</div>
```

Then, some CSS for that new class:

```
.myshortcode {
   /* some CSS here */
}
```

Comment: I added wrapper div with the class but is not working, I even echoed a div outiside the query with no success.

Comment: Also not sure why you have the function wporg_shortcodes_init() in there. You have a function inside the function, which might evaluate OK (both functions will be executed, I think, as separate function); that's sort of weird. The add_shortcode part should take care of processing the shortcode.

Comment: I took the example from the wordpress docs..https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/basic-shortcodes/